# Prompt user to scroll iOS popup window

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, scroll, popup

I've got an iPad application that uses a popup window to show filtered results based on a partial match of text. The user types into a text field, and a popup window shows the results that match. There might be 1 result, or there might be 200.

If there's more than will fit into the table view in the popup window, there's really no visual indicator that says "scroll down and you'll see more". Some users have been missing the fact that they can scroll and see more results.

What is the best way to prompt the user to scroll through the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[yourTable flashScrollIndicators];
```

This will show `scrollindicator` while scrolling, indicating that there are no of rows in the table.

Hope this will help you.